# Ordinary least squares with glmnet and lm

Tags: r, lm, least-squares, glmnet

This question was asked in [stackoverflow.com/q/38378118](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38378118) but there was no satisfactory answer.

LASSO with λ = 0 is equivalent to ordinary least squares, but this does not seem to be the case for `glmnet()` and `lm()` in R. Why?

```
library(glmnet)
options(scipen = 999)

X = model.matrix(mpg ~ 0 + ., data = mtcars)
y = as.matrix(mtcars["mpg"])
coef(glmnet(X, y, lambda = 0))
lm(y ~ X)
```

Their regression coefficients agree by at most 2 significant figures, perhaps due to slightly different termination conditions of their optimization algorithms:

```
                  glmnet        lm
(Intercept)  12.19850081  12.30337
cyl          -0.09882217  -0.11144
disp          0.01307841   0.01334
hp           -0.02142912  -0.02148
drat          0.79812453   0.78711
wt           -3.68926778  -3.71530
qsec          0.81769993   0.82104
vs            0.32109677   0.31776
am            2.51824708   2.52023
gear          0.66755681   0.65541
carb         -0.21040602  -0.19942
```

The difference is much worse when we add interaction terms.

```
X = model.matrix(mpg ~ 0 + . + . * disp, data = mtcars)
y = as.matrix(mtcars["mpg"])
coef(glmnet(X, y, lambda = 0))
lm(y ~ X)
```

Regression coefficients:

```
                     glmnet           lm
(Intercept)   36.2518682237  139.9814651
cyl          -11.9551206007  -26.0246050
disp          -0.2871942149   -0.9463428
hp            -0.1974440651   -0.2620506
drat          -4.0209186383  -10.2504428
wt             1.3612184380    5.4853015
qsec           2.3549189212    1.7690334
vs           -25.7384282290  -47.5193122
am           -31.2845893123  -47.4801206
gear          21.1818220135   27.3869365
carb           4.3160891408    7.3669904
cyl:disp       0.0980253873    0.1907523
disp:hp        0.0006066105    0.0006556
disp:drat      0.0040336452    0.0321768
disp:wt       -0.0074546428   -0.0228644
disp:qsec     -0.0077317305   -0.0023756
disp:vs        0.2033046078    0.3636240
disp:am        0.2474491353    0.3762699
disp:gear     -0.1361486900   -0.1963693
disp:carb     -0.0156863933   -0.0188304
```

Comment: try posting this on cross validated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check out these [two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56730/cannot-reproduce-ols-result-using-lasso-with-lambda-0) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378118/lasso-with-lambda-0-and-ols-produce-different-results-in-r-glmnet), you will get a sense as to why you are not getting the same results.

In essence, `glmnet` penalized maximum likelihood using a regularization path to estimate the model. `lm` solves the least squares problem using QR decomposition. So the estimates will never be exactly the same.

However, note in the manual for `?glmnet` under "lambda":

> WARNING: use with care. Do not supply a single value for lambda (for
>   predictions after CV use predict() instead). Supply instead a
>   decreasing sequence of lambda values. glmnet relies on its warms
>   starts for speed, and its often faster to fit a whole path than
>   compute a single fit.

You can do (at least) three things to get the coefficients closer so the difference is trivial--(1) have a range of values for `lambda`, (2) decrease the threshold value `thres`, and (3) increase the max number of iterations.

```
library(glmnet)
options(scipen = 999)

X = model.matrix(mpg ~ 0 + ., data = mtcars)
y = as.matrix(mtcars["mpg"])
lfit <- glmnet(X, y, lambda = rev(0:99), thres = 1E-10)
lmfit <- lm(y ~ X)
coef(lfit, s = 0) - coef(lmfit)
11 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
                          1
(Intercept)  0.004293053125
cyl         -0.000361655351
disp        -0.000002631747
hp           0.000006447138
drat        -0.000065394578
wt           0.000180943607
qsec        -0.000079480187
vs          -0.000462099248
am          -0.000248796353
gear        -0.000222035415
carb        -0.000071164178
```

---

```
X = model.matrix(mpg ~ 0 + . + . * disp, data = mtcars)
y = as.matrix(mtcars["mpg"])
lfit <- glmnet(X, y, lambda = rev(0:99), thres = 1E-12, maxit = 10^7)
lmfit <- glm(y ~ X)
coef(lfit, s = 0) - coef(lmfit)
 20 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
                           1
(Intercept) -0.3174019115228
cyl          0.0414909318817
disp         0.0020032493403
hp           0.0001834076765
drat         0.0188376047769
wt          -0.0120601219002
qsec         0.0019991131315
vs           0.0636756040430
am           0.0439343002375
gear        -0.0161102501755
carb        -0.0088921918062
cyl:disp    -0.0002714213271
disp:hp     -0.0000001211365
disp:drat   -0.0000859742667
disp:wt      0.0000462418947
disp:qsec   -0.0000175276420
disp:vs     -0.0004657059892
disp:am     -0.0003517289096
disp:gear    0.0001629963377
disp:carb    0.0000085312911
```

Some of the differences for the interacted model are probably non-trivial, but closer.