# Force glmnet to behave like glm?

Tags: r, glmnet, regularized

I would like to compare my elastic net model to a unregularized model. For the sake of fairness and simplicity, I would like to train both models using the `glmnet` package. However, I recently discovered that `glmnet` overrides `lambda=0` on some datasets.

How can I force `glmnet` to behave like `glm`?

```
x <- structure(c(0.028, 0.023, 0.0077, 0.14, 0.027, 0.084, 0.018, 
                 0.055, 0.0089, 0.016, 0.037, 0.043, 0.046, 0.031, 0.034, 0.056, 
                 0.016, 0.048, 0.013, 0.02, 0.067, 0.046, 0.058, 0.054, 0.036, 
                 0.043, 0.009, 0.12, 0.024, 0.018, 0.066, 0.046, 0.057, 0.054, 
                 0.036, 0.043, 0.009, 0.12, 0.024, 0.018, 0.051, 0.043, 0.047, 
                 0.045, 0.034, 0.04, 0.009, 0.085, 0.022, 0.016, 0.028, 0.023, 
                 0.0089, 0.14, 0.028, 0.084, 0.02, 0.055, 0.0089, 0.016, 0.067, 
                 0.049, 0.058, 0.055, 0.038, 0.043, 0.009, 0.12, 0.024, 0.018, 
                 0.067, 0.046, 0.058, 0.054, 0.036, 0.043, 0.009, 0.12, 0.024, 
                 0.018), .Dim = c(10L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
y <- gl(2, 5)
fit <- glmnet::glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", lambda = 0)
fit$lambda # should be 0 but actually infinity
```

```
Warning messages:
1: In lognet(xd, is.sparse, ix, jx, y, weights, offset, alpha, nobs,  :
  one multinomial or binomial class has fewer than 8  observations; dangerous ground
2: from glmnet Fortran code (error code -1); Convergence for 1th lambda value not reached after maxit=100000 iterations; solutions for larger lambdas returned 
3: In getcoef(fit, nvars, nx, vnames) :
  an empty model has been returned; probably a convergence issue
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, some of the predictors are highly correlated, for example between 3,4,7,8, it's essentially the same values:

```
round(cor(x),3)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]
[1,] 1.000 0.308 0.290 0.294 0.330 1.000 0.292 0.290
[2,] 0.308 1.000 0.653 0.652 0.730 0.306 0.660 0.653
[3,] 0.290 0.653 1.000 1.000 0.989 0.285 0.999 1.000
[4,] 0.294 0.652 1.000 1.000 0.989 0.290 0.999 1.000
[5,] 0.330 0.730 0.989 0.989 1.000 0.325 0.992 0.989
[6,] 1.000 0.306 0.285 0.290 0.325 1.000 0.287 0.285
[7,] 0.292 0.660 0.999 0.999 0.992 0.287 1.000 0.999
[8,] 0.290 0.653 1.000 1.000 0.989 0.285 0.999 1.000
```

One of the purpose of a penalized regression is to drop correlated variables and improve the regression. From [glmnet vigette](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html):

> It is known that the ridge penalty shrinks the coefficients of
> correlated predictors towards each other while the lasso tends to pick
> one of them and discard the others. The elastic net penalty mixes
> these two: if predictors are correlated in groups, an =0.5 tends to
> either select or leave out the entire group of features. This is a
> higher level parameter, and users might pick a value upfront or
> experiment with a few different values. One use of  is for numerical
> stability; for example, the elastic net with =1− for some small
> >0 performs much like the lasso, but removes any degeneracies and
> wild behavior caused by extreme correlations.

If you set lambda to be 0, it's going to be very hard to reach convergence, because how do you determine the coefficient for highly correlated variables? It is touched upon in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378118/lasso-with-lambda-0-and-ols-produce-different-results-in-r-glmnet) you can set `thres` to a small value but I doubt it will work in your case, because the correlations are too high.

To prove this, let's change the x to a random normal matrix and you can see it converges:

```
fit = glmnet::glmnet(matrix(rnorm(80),ncol=8), y, family = "binomial", lambda = 0)

Call:  glmnet::glmnet(x = matrix(rnorm(80), ncol = 8), y = y, family = "binomial",      lambda = 0) 

  Df %Dev Lambda
1  8  100      0
```

In summary, I would think about the purpose of comparison. If you have a lot of predictors, many correlated, it is obvious that an unregularized regression would perform poorly, stating the case for something like `glmnet`. You can just use `glm` to prove your point. Otherwise consider removing highly correlated predictors.